# PNAgent IconCache size increases after every windows logon

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, citrix

Xenapp 6.5 farm with Webinterface 5.4.0 on WinServer2008R2
Citrix Online Plugin 12.3.08

After login to a standard Windows7 machine, Citrix Online Plugin gets automatically started. The Logon process to the Webinterface works and then there is a minute gap, where you can't even right click on Citrix Online Plugin.

First resarches showed, that in this time the IconCache in %localappdata%\Citrix\PnAgent\IconCache gets refresehed. This applies after every logon to the windows user profile. But not on simple restart of Citrix online Plugin and pnagent.exe.

During this IconCache update, the some (not all) Icons get touched (changed write time) and filesize of the icons changes. On the changed icons you can see, that there are more frames in the file as before. So the same icon got new frames (which looks exactly like the other frames). After deleting all icons and refresh the cache, some icons have 3 frames with 48x48x32,32x32x32,16x16x32 and some only 2 frames with 32x32x32 and 16x16x32.
Only the icons with 3 frames are touched after the next logon.

The %localappdata% isn't synchronized to a server, so all files are only local on the clients harddisk and are kept after logoff (and reboot).

Any ideas on what to look for? 
The 1-minute gap is really anoying for users, which only work with citrix.

Comment: 12.3 is 3½ years old, is no longer supported and has been superseded several times. This might even be a known bug. Is there a reason why you don't upgrade clients to the latest Receiver version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are at version 12.3 because of a management decision. But anyway:

We had a GroupPolicy RegistryPreference which deleted the `HKCU:\Software\Citrx\PNagent` everytime.
In this location the ItemProperty `IconDatabase Model 000` stores which icons are already cached (btw. only the high res icons are listed there). If this key is deleted, Citrix Online Plugin refreshes the IconCache under `%localappdata/Citrix/PnAgent/IconCache%` even if there are the icons already. A bit strange is the behaviour, that the ICO-Files are merged and not replaced.